# What's the benefit of JWT if user needs to send his credentials once anyway?

Tags: jwt

JWT tokens seem like a very good idea. You can send a request to some API without using your username/password secret pair.

Still, I don't fully understand the benefits that it gives. I have two questions:

1. To get the token, user still needs to send his credentials to some server that issues these tokens. Isn't it a weak point of all this?
2. If attacker steals the token while it's being transferred, he can use it to pretend he is someone else. The only difference between this and using user/password combination is that JWT tokens get expired after some period of time, so attacker doesn't have much time to do his thing.

Is my understanding correct? What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe I should post this in InformationSecurity StackExchange? Am I able to move it instead of creating duplicate question there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it does have to exchange the pair once, but this is still minimised risk compared to doing it every time you have to make an API call.
2. There are many ways tokens can be stolen, and the common way to detect this is by checking for sudden unexpected changes in IP addresses. This method is not robust and is easily spoofed. However, if we're able to detect the theft, then it's a simple matter of blacklisting the token. Hence, the entire strategy is dependent on detecting that the theft has occurred. For this reason, you should use the concept of rotating tokens: See more in [this blog](https://hackernoon.com/the-best-way-to-securely-manage-user-sessions-91f27eeef460) for how this would work as it's too long to explain in a SO answer.